# Stumbleupon API url encoding problem

Tags: api, url-encoding, apprequests

I am trying to work with the stumbleupon API to get information about the items on my site.

Documentation: http://www.stumbleupon.com/help/badge-api-documentation/

Now it works perfectly except with some URL's...

But `http://lolbin.net/i/fp16jU82/that's-what-beer-is-for.htm` for example has a ' in the URL, which is a problem for the Stumbleupon API.

I have tried various things, but I keep getting error pages:

```
http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=http://lolbin.net/i/fp16jU82/that's-what-beer-is-for.html

http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=http://lolbin.net/i/fp16jU82/that\'s-what-beer-is-for.html

http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=http://lolbin.net/i/fp16jU82/that%27s-what-beer-is-for.html

http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=http://lolbin.net/i/fp16jU82/that%252527s-what-beer-is-for.html
```

The item is in the stumbleupon database already with many views: http://www.stumbleupon.com/url/lolbin.net/i/fp16jU82/that%252527s-what-beer-is-for.html

**My question is, how can I query this particular item via the API so I get a valid return?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with %2527

```
http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=http://lolbin.net/i/fp16jU82/that%2527s-what-beer-is-for.html
```

Returns:

```
{"result":{"url":"http:\/\/lolbin.net\/i\/fp16jU82\/that%27s-what-beer-is-for.html",
"in_index":true,"publicid":"Aq9jhK","views":262882,
"title":"Thats what beer is for - LOLBIN.net","thumbnail":"http:\/\/cdn.stumble-upon.com\/mthumb\/767\/82718767.jpg",
"thumbnail_b":"http:\/\/cdn.stumble-upon.com\/altbthumb\/767\/82718767.jpg","submit_link":
"http:\/\/www.stumbleupon.com\/submit?url=http:\/\/lolbin.net\/i\/fp16jU82\/that%27s-what-beer-is-for.html","badge_link":
"http:\/\/www.stumbleupon.com\/badge?url=http:\/\/lolbin.net\/i\/fp16jU82\/that%27s-what-beer-is-for.html",
"info_link":"http:\/\/www.stumbleupon.com\/url\/lolbin.net\/i\/fp16jU82\/that%252527s-what-beer-is-for.html"},
"timestamp":1317025970,"success":true}
```

It is, as Godius pointed out, a double urlencoding. ' => %27 => %2527

Comment: It's strange that, in your question, you had tried single-encoding the URL [`%27`], and triple encoding it [`%252527`], but not double-encoding it. It's always the last thing you try.